# How do I set default screen size for headless machine?

Tags: 11.10, resolution, screen, headless

Vanilla 11.10 install. I want the default resolution to be 1920x1080 instead of 1024x768 when I access from a Windows 7 box using TightVNC client. I've not installed any new VNC s/w on Ubuntu. Where is the default resolution defined (or assumed) when no monitor is attached? I am very new to Ubuntu. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What VNC server are you using ? Typically you set the display resolution when you start the server, for example with TightVNC

```
vncserver -geometry 1920x1080
```

Please update your question and identify which VNC server you are using.

Comment: I was using default vnc but have given up and use Windows remote desktop now, which works.  The 12.04 upgrade also reinstated the settings cogwheel dropdown.